# Upgraded to EF Core 3.1 and now IProperty.get_ClrType is missing

Tags: ef-core-3.0

When I upgraded my project from EF Core 2.2 to EF Core 3.1 I started getting this error:

> Method not found: 'System.Type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty.get_ClrType()'.

This is in a [Breeze module](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/0b7f206984e3dd874b7e4ef7459202e29495fc58/AspNetCore/Breeze.Persistence.EFCore/MetadataBuilder.cs#L95).

I looked in the [Breaking Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#xinfo) and could not see anything that matches this (though it could be that the metadata references are including this and I just don't understand them).

**Is this supposed to be missing?  Is there a workaround?**

Comment: https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/0b7f206984e3dd874b7e4ef7459202e29495fc58/AspNetCore/Breeze.Persistence.EFCore/Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.csproj#L4 and https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/0b7f206984e3dd874b7e4ef7459202e29495fc58/AspNetCore/Breeze.Persistence.EFCore/Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.csproj#L31

Comment: @IvanStoev - Yeah. It has been working fine with .Net Core 3.  So I thought it may be fine with EF Core 3 too.  I already rolled back to EF Core 2.2.  But I am still curious if this missing method was an intended breaking change to EF Core 3, or a mistake or something else...

Comment: The change is intentional, but you won't find it in the list (as many others).So take it this way. EF Core 3.0 is a breaking release and requires updating and recompiling the libraries which use EF Core.

Comment: I get EntityName from Property.ClrType as follows : eti.EntityName = iet.ClrType.Name. There are dozens of attributes. I don't know which one you want, maybe UnderlyingSystemType ? Better take a look yourself.