# Clean up for EF Core's GetDbConnection?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

My application needs a way to call a sproc and get random data back from it.  Because I am using BreezeJS, I cannot use a `DbQuery` (or keyless `DbSet`).

I [put together a method](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/99561ffb5b0d1d02ffe18b28edfaa3bf) that will perform the query using `DbCommand`.  However it uses the following code:

```
var conn = efCoreContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
conn.Open();
```

I know that making any kind of connection can easily be done wrong.  I am specifically wondering if:

- I need any kind of connection pooling?
- I need to clean up the resulting connection's resources?
- Any other drawback to connecting like this?

Comment: Use a `using` block to ensure the connection is disposed. That's still a connection. Connection pooling is already implemented by the underlying driver. Why *can't* you use EF Core properly though?  BreezeJS is a client library, it doesn't put any constraints on how the data access code used by the front-end HTTP services works

Comment: You should probably consider upgrading to EF Core 3.1 too. It's a .NET Standard 2.0 package, so it works on .NET Core 2.x. It solves many of EF Core 2.2's issues. Finally, if you can't use the ORM, perhaps you shouldn't. You could use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) and eg `conn.Query<ThatDTO>(someSQL)` to get but a `List<ThatDTO>` directly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - BreezeJs has a server side component too.  It takes all the DbSets and DbQuerys to make metadata for the client side.  It treats the DbSets and DbQuerys the same (as entities).  It then fails because the DbQuery does not have a Key defined.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I tried to upgrade to EF Core 3.  BreezeJs's server side component uses features that were removed in EF Core 3 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59205665/upgraded-to-ef-core-3-1-and-now-iproperty-get-clrtype-is-missing)

Comment: if Breeze requires a key, your own method won't work either

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - This data is not meant for Breeze to consume.  If I could get it to ignore the DbQuery I would use that because I don't need/want Breeze to know about it.  But the only way to get Breeze to ignore a DbQuery/DbSet is to build up the metadata separate from the automatic process.

Comment: have you tried Dapper? Or using a *different* DbContext entirely? I just saw that the NuGet packages are 1 year old *but* there's work going on on an [ASP.NET Core 3 repo](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/tree/master/AspNetCore-v3)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I have tried Dapper.  But BreezeJs integrates deeply into Entity Framework and not Dapper.  Also this is an existing product.  Migration to Dapper would be a lot of work that could not be justified for need of a Stored Procedure call.  I have considered a different DbContext.  But that adds a lot of complexity to the application just to perform a Stored Procedure call.  I would rather not do it.

Comment: On the contrary, only the simplest applications can use a single DbContext. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, it should only contain the entities needed for a single scenario. It's not a model of the database. *Especially* in older EF versions, big contexts resulted in very slow startup

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - We have digressed from the original question.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: Not at all. The *simple* solution is to just split the context. If you have entities that aren't needed the front end, don't put them in the same context.

Comment: Besides, what *do* you want? You said those entities shouldn't be used with Breeze, that's why you can load them separately. But then you say you can't use Dapper because you *do* want to use them with Breeze. In that case your code won't work. What do you want after all? You can use EF and Dapper. You can use just EF with different contexts. If you don't want either option, why, and what are you looking for?

Comment: just return a id field with a value = 0 and add id to model.    thats what we do for all issues like that if you cant use ef core 3